# counting the result of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, counting

```
Person table
---------------------
|email (pk)   | name|
---------------------
|a@hotmail.com| A   |
|b@hotmail.com| B   |
|c@hotmail.com| C   |

 Role table
---------------------------------
|Role               |Power     |
-------------------------------|
|Primary            |20        |
|Secondary          |10        |
|Supervisor         |30        |
--------------------------------
Assignment table
------------------------------------------------------------------
|Team Name| Term    | Role      |Email         |Join_date
------------------------------------------------------------------
|AA       |2013_1   |Supervisor |a@hotmail.com |2013-08-05
|BB       |2013_1   |Secondary  |a@hotmail.com |2013-08-05
|CC       |2013_1   |Supervisor |c@hotmail.com |2013-08-05
|DD       |2013_1   |Secondary  |a@hotmail.com |2013-08-05
|AA       |2013_1   |Secondary  |b@hotmail.com |2013-08-05
```

My expected result

```
|name | email        | num_of_time_pri | num_of_time_sec | num_of_time_sup|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|A    | a@hotmail.com|0                |2                | 1              |
|B    | b@hotmail.com|0                |1                | 0              |
|C    | c@hotmail.com|0                |0                | 1              |
```

Given a term, eg `2013_1` I have to find all the person who is assigned to least one role. And count how many of each role the person is assigned to.

Using this query:

```
select 
      distinct p.name,
      p.email 
 from assignment a,person p 
 where term ='2013_1' and 
       a.email = p.email;
```

assume it returns 3 rows as seen in person table. And from there, I want to get the expected result table. How do I continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate `case` statement. And, as much as possible refrain from using the `implicit join`.

```
select 
      p.name,
      p.email,
      sum(case when role='Primary' then 1 else 0 end) as num_of_time_pri,
      sum(case when role='Secondary' then 1 else 0 end) as num_of_time_sec,
      sum(case when role='Supervisor' then 1 else 0 end) as num_of_time_sup
from assignment a
inner join person p on a.email = p.email
where term ='2013_1'
group by p.name,p.email;
```

OR

```
select 
      p.name,
      p.email,
      count(case when role='Primary' then 1 end) as num_of_time_pri,
      count(case when role='Secondary' then 1 end) as num_of_time_sec,
      count(case when role='Supervisor' then 1 end) as num_of_time_sup
from assignment a
inner join person p on a.email = p.email
where term ='2013_1'
group by p.name,p.email;
```

Comment: It's just if the row has a role which is 'Primary' it will return the true condition which is 1.Then by the use of sum, it will give the total of the rows which have role is equal to 'Primary'. So on to 'Supervisor' and 'Secondary'.

Comment: is it possible to achieve the same result using `count()`? i've tried all sorts of way. One issue was, when person C who was not assigned as sec or pri, the query excluded person C entirely.

Comment: Yes, `Count` is also possible in my answer.

Comment: i noticed when using `sum` when a person is not assigned a specific role, the result came back as `null` instead of `0`